# Page thumbnails for pdf-tools?

Tags: pdf-tools, image-dired

**Q:** is there an [`image-dired`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html) analog to make thumbnails in [`pdf-tools`](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools)?

[`image-dired`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Image_002dDired.html) provides
facilities to browse images in a directory by thumbnail.  Is there
analogous functionality
for [`pdf-tools`](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools)?

The use case I see is in jumping to different pages.  `pdf-tools`
allows us to select pages by number, but blindly.  I often don't
remember which page I want by number, but could easier figure it
out if I had thumbnails.

Comment: I suspect there isn't such a thing, but it would be a really useful feature!